# Link URL gets cut off after special character

Tags: html, jsp, web

I have a button on my home page. The link contains a question mark
example

```
  http://url.com/my_app/#/store/items?page=2
```

this is the code for my button

```
<form action="http://url.com/my_app/#/store/items?page=2" method="get">
    <input type="submit" value="Click here">
</form>
```

The link doesn't take you to the correct site. The URL is cut off after the "?" like so

```
http://url.com/my_app/#/store/items
```

I tried to use ascii encoding but it still fails the same

```
<form action="http://url.com/my_app/#/store/items%3Fpage=2" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <input type="submit" value="Click here">
</form>
```

To me it looks like the question mark is a special character and needs to be escaped but I haven't seen a similar question online.

Does anyone know why the URL is being cut off?

Answer (score 1):

*Hidden* inputs can be used to send additional information that you want to process along with the form information. This should fix the issue:

```
<form action="http://url.com/my_app/#/store/items" method="get">
   <input type="hidden" name="page" value="2"/>
   <input type="submit" value="Click here">
</form>
```

Comment: I see. But I have the URL I'm using isn't static- it is stored in a variable and am calling it from form so the hidden input wouldn't work too well =/

Comment: @spaz what about using .htaccess, to get rid of question mark?